# Crossing the integer limits in PHP

Tags: php, math, integer, integer-overflow

Can someone please explain what is happening in the last 2 cases?

```
$x=PHP_INT_MAX;
var_dump($x);            // int(9223372036854775807)        no problem
var_dump($x+1);          // float(9.2233720368548E+18)      value is cast to float still no problem
var_dump($x+1-1);        // float(9.2233720368548E+18)      still okay
var_dump((int)($x+1-1)); // int(-9223372036854775808)       negative value?!!
var_dump($x+1-$x);       // float(0)                        zero?!!!!!!!!!!!
```

According to the [PHP manual](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.integer.php):

> - PHP_INT_MAX is the maximum integer size.
> - If PHP encounters a number beyond the bounds of the integer type, it will be interpreted as a float instead. Also, an operation which
>     results in a number beyond the bounds of the integer type will return
>     a float instead.

So the first 2 dumps are okay. The third dump gives the expected result, but why on earth does the last two dumps give a negative value and zero?

Comment: This has to do with how the computer stores numbers. Specifically negative numbers and float numbers.

Answer (score 1):

Two different things are combining: floating point rounding and integer overflow.

```
var_dump($x+1-$x);       // float(0)                        zero?!!!!!!!!!!!
```

This is because [floating point](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating_point) arithmetic is not exact (it can't be, as real numbers can be infinite). `$x` and `$x+1` are so close together that they are rounded to the same floating point value, so `float($x+1)==float($x)`. Now you know why `$x+1-$x==0`.

Combined with integer overflow you get this result:

```
var_dump((int)($x+1-1)); // int(-9223372036854775808)       negative value?!!
```

Because of the reason above `$x+1-1==float(9223372036854775808)`. When casting this to an `int` it [overflows](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer_overflow) and becomes a negative value.

`9223372036854775808==2^63`, which in 64-bit signed integers becomes `-2^63`

Answer (score 0):

About the 4th test:
Integers are signed. Internally they are stored in such a way, that when you add one, the value wraps and turns into the lowest negative integer. In case of a signed nibble of 4 bits, this would look like:

```
0111 (=7) + 0001 (=1) = 1000 (= -7)
```

This explains partially how a number can suddenly become a very large negative number.

But you would expect x+1-1 to be x, but it is probably an issue with significant digits. PHP stores only 14 significant digits, which is not enough to store a number like `9223372036854775807` exactly without losing information.

I'll explain using the 5th test:

A floating point can contain much bigger numbers than an integer, but only with a limited number of significant digits. That's why it looks like `9.2233720368548E+18` instead of `9223372036854800000` or `9223372036854775808`.

Since low numbers like `1` are outside of the significant digits of the value, I think `9.2233720368548E+18 + 1` is still `9.2233720368548E+18`. That also means that `9.2233720368548E+18 + 1 - 9.2233720368548E+18` is `0`, because the `+1` just didn't have any effect.

I think this is actually the explanation for both fenomena.

The weird thing is that you would normally not have to know about any of these implementation details, especially in a scripting language like PHP, but in tests like this, they may surface anyway and sometimes cause weird behavior.

Also, you might want to read [The PHP floating point precision is wrong by default](http://www.leaseweblabs.com/2013/06/the-php-floating-point-precision-is-wrong-by-default/). It contains a good explanation of other rounding errors that might occur using floats, and it will give you a deeper understanding of how floats work in general and in PHP specifically.

Answer (score 0):

This has to do with how the computer stores numbers. In this case, signed numbers, meaning they can both be negative and positive.

For the sake of it I will use an 8-bit example. The computer can store numbers from `-128` to `127`.
`-128` is represented as `1000 0000` while `127` is presented as `0111 1111`. The first bit represents if the number is negative or positive. Every bit is worth `2^n`, were `n` is the position from right to left. For 127 it is `2^0 + 2^1 + 2^2 + 2^3 + 2^4 + 2^5 + 2^6 + 2^7 = 127.` The opposite for a negative value.

```
var_dump($x);            // int(9223372036854775807)        no problem
```

No problems because we are just setting it to the maximum value.

```
var_dump($x+1);          // float(9.2233720368548E+18)      value is cast to float still no problem
var_dump($x+1-1);        // float(9.2233720368548E+18)      still okay
```

Here there are problems, +1 and +1-1 equals to the same thing. Which they should not, problem does occur here, a bit more subtle.

```
var_dump((int)($x+1-1)); // int(-9223372036854775808)       negative value?!!
```

In this case `0111 (...)` +1 equals to `1000 (...)` which is the absolute value, notice the 8 in the end of the number, compared to the 7 for the positive value. **Overflow flag in CPU is set.**

```
var_dump($x+1-$x);       // float(0)                        zero?!!!!!!!!!!!
```

$x+1 forces a cast to float, then subtracts the same value (because of rounding errors with float numbers), $x+1 is the same as $x, so $x-$x = 0.

Hope this clarifies some.

Comment: Your integer overflow explanation is correct, but you do not correctly explain `var_dump($x+1-$x); // float(0)`. Float's do not overflow in this situation.